# Excel Chart, Named Range, Exclude the word "Date"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I went the named range route when creating a chart because I want it to auto update whenever I add new data to the range.

However when I want the date listed on the x axis the word "date" is also being shown.

[image]

my named range is like so `=OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1)`

I have tried switching to A2, but then I get 0 data for  30/06/2016 ?

[image]

How can I exclude "Date" on my x axis ?

Here is my data:

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your data... Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1376020/edit) to include it?

Comment: included my date column.. the rest are a few columns full of data.

Comment: What happens when you right-click on the chart and `select data`? is the correct range selected?

Comment: your named range for the axis should be `=OFFSET($A$2,0,0,COUNTA(A:A)-1,1)` and also ensure the named range for the series starts in ROW 2 also